# I keep getting a web driver exception error while also working sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I keep getting a variety of WebDriver errors and then randomly it will run properly. How do i fix the error that is happening so that i can run the full version of what i am trying to do?

The latest one was : WebDriverException: unknown error: unexpected command response
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

ytournaments = ['/dpworld-tour/abu-dhabi-hsbc-championship-2021/', '/dpworld-tour/omega-dubai-desert-classic-2021/']

roundids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for tournamentid in ytournaments:
    
    for roundid in roundids:
        
        page = driver.get(f"https://www.europeantour.com{tournamentid}leaderboard?holebyhole=true&round={roundid}")
        time.sleep(10)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        
        Tour = 'European Tour'
        Year = '2021'
        
        tournamentm = soup.find('h1', class_='event-hero__title').text
        tournament = tournamentm.strip()
        
        coursem = soup.find('p', class_='event-hero__location').text
        course = coursem.strip()
        
        datem = soup.find('p', class_='event-hero__date').text
        date = datem.strip()
        
        dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
        df = dfs[0]
        ndf = np.squeeze(dfs)
        data = pd.DataFrame(ndf)
        
        data["tournament"] = tournament
        data["course"] = course
        data["date"] = date
        data["roundid"] = roundid
        data["Tour"] = Tour
        data["Year"] = Year
        
        filename = f'{tournament}_{roundid}_{Year}.csv'
        data.to_csv(filename)
    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with 103.0.5060.66

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121

From the link above here is a possible solution for now:

"Untill the issue is fixed "Downgrade Chrome Version to 102" and install "Selenium Chrome Driver v102" your script will run without any issue, As I had suggested "Comment 32" today I tried it and it worked without any issue"

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have updated Google Chrome? Check Google Chrome version in Google settings / About Chrome. e.g.: My Chrome version is 103.0.5060.66

Download and update Chromedriver to the version of your browser. Hope this helps.